# Is there any restriction to the number of processes that can join a multicast group when using ZeroMQ epgm transport?

Tags: multicast, zeromq

Is there any restriction to the number of process that can join a multicast group when using ZeroMQ epgm transport.

I'm using loopback interface in EPGM as of now. 
   zmq_connect(subscriber,"epgm://127.0.0.1;239.192.1.1:5555);

All the processes are on same Linux machine. Is there any restriction to the number of processes that can communicate (send as well as receive messages) over this interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is set by your network switch.